# applescript move folder script

Tags: applescript, duplicates

I am a complete applescript virgin and I have 2 versions of the same application that use different frameworks that have the same name.

I'm looking to create 2 scripts that move the correct version of the framework into the frameworks folder so I can swap them out quickly from the desktop.

This is what I have so far but it is throwing up an AppleEvent Handler failed -10000 error.

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "Machintosh HD/Framework Store/Test.framework" to POSIX file "Machintosh HD/Library/Frameworks/Test.framework" with replacing
end tell
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed you also had the Had disk name. The first forward slash "/" is all you need to refer to that.

```
 tell application "Finder"
    set rootFolder to POSIX file "/Framework Store/Test.framework"
    set targetFolder to POSIX file "/Library/Frameworks/"
        duplicate rootFolder to targetFolder with replacing
  end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "Machintosh HD/Framework Store/Test.framework" to POSIX file "Machintosh HD/Library/Frameworks" with replacing
end tell
```

Comment: To explain this answer: The correct use is to tell finder which object to move and the  new location for the object. You do not need to add on the end of the new location the object itself. This answer shows that by removing "Test.framework" from the end of the code

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tried that but it is still throwing up the AppleEvent handler error.